# How to process signed numbers in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am processing a .txt file
in source and  I have a data +120.2894.
I want to push the data to sql db using adf dataflow activity.
Automatically it takes string datatype and makes the output as +120.29 which is precise upto two decimal places.
I have tried decimal l(15,4) using a cast activity but it remives the + sign and gives the output as 120.2894.

I need the data in as usual format and the output shouold be +120.2894.
Please let me know how I can do the cast in adf?

Ps:-The column also contains negative records.

Comment: In SQL also if you ass no with `+` sign in a decimal column it will not show the sign when you view that table only `-` sign is visible. If you still wand data as `+120.2894` you need to store it as String (varchar) otherwise it will remove positive sign

Comment: you will get positive negative record like this in SQL [this](https://i.imgur.com/pyE0VHb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL or data factory If it detects Number with `+` sign It will not show it the sign is only visible for `-` numbers.

Sample data:
[image]

Go to projection of source >> Import projection it will detect schema of column.
[image]

Data preview for it:( It will only show  `-` sign for numbers)
[image]

Output: (same in sql database)
[image]

> If you still want data as `+120.2894` you need to store it as String (varchar).

Go to projection of source >> Import projection it will detect schema of column >> then select string type for respective column.
[image]

Data preview for it:
[image]

Output:
[image]